# django generic DetailView

Tags: django, detailview

New to django and really like the simplicity in getting things done. However having problem rendering a generic DetailView as I get a 405 error stating method not supported. Below is my code.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, get_list_or_404
from django.views.generic import View, ListView, DetailView
from store.managers import StoreManager
from .models import Store

# Create your views here.
class StoreDetails(DetailView):
    model = Store
    template_name = 'store/details.html'

class StoreIndex(ListView):
    model = Store
    template_name = 'store/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'stores'
# url 
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^view/([0-9]+)/$', StoreDetails.as_view(), name='details'),
url(r'^index/$', StoreIndex.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

While my StoreIndex view works perfectly, I get an error for my StoreDetails view. Tried overriding get_context_data function but same result.

Comment: Could you add your `urls` please?

Comment: Here is my url: urlpatterns = [url(r'^view/([0-9]+)/$', StoreDetails.as_view(), name='details'),]

Comment: Have you tried adding a `get` function to your view?

Comment: I didn't add a "get" function since I am using a generic view, I only thought of extending my template_name and let django handle the rest. In any case, adding a get function has same result

Comment: What is the stack trace?

Comment: I only get a blank page with a 404. From the terminal I have: System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 26, 2015 - 23:48:27
Django version 1.8.4, using settings 'myapp.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[26/Dec/2015 23:48:33] "GET /store/details/1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 5653
[26/Dec/2015 23:48:49] "GET /store/view/1/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0

Comment: I just wondered, because this error usually appears in cbv (generally in a class which inherits from `View`), if one did not implement `get` or `post`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the url pattern. The `DetailView` needs the primary key to find the right object to display, but the pattern `r'^view/([0-9]+)/$'` does not specify that the matching number should be used as the primary key. Try `r'^view/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$'` (`pk` stands for primary key).

Also see the example at [DetailView doocs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) (which provides `slug` instead of `pk`). Custom `get_context_data` should not be neede for `pk` and `slug`.

Comment: Modified the urlpatterns as suggested but not getting desired result. Will further look into this. Thanks for the helping hand.

Comment: It would be great to see the exact error ... do you have any logging set up? Do you have `DEBUG=True` set in your `settings.py`? That might help and print the exception (either in-browser, or on the console when run as `./manage.py runserver`.

Comment: I finally fixed the issue and realised why I was not getting any StackTrace. I had mistakenly left an older version of the StoreDetails view class in the same file as the updated copy. Having the two classes with the older being later in file was setting my urlpattern to use the older view class and not the corrected version. Deleting the old and adding the url regex param as you suggested fixed these. Thanks